# sync Safari tabs but not history between iPhone and MacBook

Tags: macos, safari, mojave, continuity

On my MacBook in System Preferences I can check Safari within the iCloud page in order to sync tabs, bookmarks, history etc. between my iPhone 7 and my MacBook.

But I don't want to sync history, so I unchecked it.

However now I can't handoff tabs from my MacBook to my iPhone (and vice versa)

How can I enable tab handoff without syncing history?